# можно ли делать массивы в массиве структур так

Tags: c

Решаю задачу:

Дан массив чисел A длины N , а также K массивов чисел M1,. . . ,MK длин m1,. . . ,mK соответ-
ственно. Требуется найти наибольший по длине массив среди M1,. . . ,MK , который может быть
получен из массива A при помощи удаления каких-либо элементов массива A. Если таких мас-
сивов несколько, выведите первый из них в лексикографическом порядке. Если такого массива
нет, выведите сообщение об ошибке.

Написал код, который вроде даже запускается и определяет есть ли нужный массив, но вот если есть, то выводит мусорные рандомные значения. Меня смущает, как я делаю массив из структуры arrays, а потом, когда уже выделил память для него, я делаю массивы в каждом из элементов массива структуры.   Буду благодарен, если укажите на ошибку!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct arrays{
    int size;
    int* data;
};

int Process(int* dataA, int* dataMi, int sizeA, int sizeMi);
int ReadArray(FILE* file, int* data, int size);
int Search(int* result, int* dataMi, int maxlen, int sizeMi);

int ReadArray(FILE* file, int* data, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(fscanf(file, "%d", data + i) != 1){
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Определние, является ли Mi подпоследовательностью A
int Process(int* dataA, int* dataMi, int sizeA, int sizeMi){
    int indicator = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++){
        if(indicator < sizeMi){
            if(dataA[i] == dataMi[indicator]){
                indicator++;
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(indicator == sizeMi){
        return sizeMi;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

// Для лексикографического порядка
int Search(int* result, int* dataMi, int maxlen, int sizeMi){
    if(sizeMi == maxlen){
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeMi; i++){
            if(result[i] < dataMi[i]){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    FILE* finA;
    FILE* finM;
    int* dataA;
    struct arrays* dataM;
    int sizeA;
    int sizeM;
    int maxlen = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    int* result;

    if((finA = fopen("inputA.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open input file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(finA, "%d", &sizeA) != 1){
        printf("Can't read size!\n");
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }

    if(sizeA < 1){
        printf("Incorrect size!\n)");
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }

    if((dataA = (int*) malloc(sizeA * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
        printf("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }

    if(ReadArray(finA, dataA, sizeA) < 0){
        printf("Can't read array!\n");
        free(dataA);
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }



    if((finM = fopen("inputM.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open input file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(finM, "%d", &sizeM) != 1){
        printf("Can't read count of files!\n");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    if(sizeM < 1){
        printf("Incorrect size!\n)");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    if((dataM = (struct arrays*) malloc(sizeM * sizeof(struct arrays))) == NULL){
        printf("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeM; i++){
        if(fscanf(finM, "%d", &dataM[i].size) != 1){
        printf("Can't read size!\n");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
        }

        if(dataM[i].size < 1){
        printf("Incorrect size!\n)");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
        }

        if((dataM[i].data = (int*) malloc(dataM[i].size * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
        printf("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
        }

        if(ReadArray(finM, dataM[i].data, dataM[i].size) < 0){
        printf("Can't read array!\n");
        free(dataM[i].data);
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
        }
    }

    // Определяем максимальную длину подпоследовательности
    for(int i=0; i < sizeM; i++){
        tmp = Process(dataA, dataM[i].data, sizeA, dataM[i].size);
        if(maxlen < tmp){
            maxlen = tmp;
        }
    }

    result = (int*) malloc(tmp * sizeof(int));

    // Находим самый первый Mi длины maxlen в лексикографическом порядке
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeM; i++){
        if(Search(result, dataM[i].data, maxlen, dataM[i].size) == 1){
            for(int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++){
                result[i] = dataM[i].data;
            }
        }
    }

    if(result == NULL){
        printf("There are no need sequences!\n");
        free(dataA);
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeM; i++){
            free(dataM[i].data);
        }
        free(dataM);
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++){
        printf("%d\n", result[i]);
    }

    free(dataA);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeM; i++){
        free(dataM[i].data);
    }
    free(dataM);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `K массивов чисел M1,. . . ,MK длин m1,. . . ,mK соответ- ственно.` не совсем понял что за структура

Comment: @DaniilLoban я хочу задать k массивов в виде структуры arrays. в ней есть число size - количество элементов в каком то массиве Mi и сам массив Mi

Comment: думаю к задече не помешал бы тестовый набор данных чтобы запустить глянуть что где не так, ну и мне почему-то кажется здесь кода в несколько раз больше чем нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мусор выводился по причине того что данные не инициировались. При выделении памяти под массив там находится мусор — случайные числа.
которые были больше имеющихся в реальном массиве.

В этой функции я поправил условие на обратное так как в лексиграфическом значении
`1 < 2` т.е. если `result = 2` а `dataM = 1` или `result > dataM`, то его нужно переписать `result = dataM` сделав `result = 1` так же нужно учесть что если в результате сравнения первых чисел нет равенства нужно выходить из цикла — при `>` и при `<` тоже:

```
// Для лексикографического порядка
int Search(int* result, int* dataMi, int maxlen, int sizeMi){
    if(sizeMi == maxlen){
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeMi; i++){
            if(result[i] != dataMi[i]){
                return  result[i] < dataMi[i] ? 0 : 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код я просто сократил:

```
// Определние, является ли Mi подпоследовательностью A
int Process(int* dataA, int* dataMi, int sizeA, int sizeMi){
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeA && size < sizeMi; i++){
        if(dataA[i] == dataMi[size]) size++;
    }
    return  size == sizeMi ? sizeMi : -1;
}
```

Я добавил в структуру булиев флаг для того чтобы помечать то что совпало

```
struct arrays{
    int size;
    int* data;
    bool isExist;
};

// Определяем максимальную длину подпоследовательности
for(int i=0; i < sizeM; i++){
    tmp = Process(dataA, dataM[i].data, sizeA, dataM[i].size);
    if (tmp != -1) dataM[i].isExist = true;
    if(maxlen < tmp) maxlen = tmp;
}
```

Этот код я немного переписал, добавив еще одну переменную А еще я заметил что `i` переназначалось внутренним циклом, так делать не стоит, поэтому ввел `j`:

```
int continueIndex = 0;  // чтобы не проходить дважды по части массива

// Находим самый первый Mi длины maxlen
for(int i = 0; i < sizeM; i++){
    continueIndex = i + 1;
    if(dataM[i].isExist == true && dataM[i].size == maxlen){
        for(int j = 0; j < maxlen; j++){
            result[j] = dataM[i].data[j];
        }
        break;
    }
}

// Выбираем массив в лексикографическом порядке с startIndex
for(int i = startIndex; i < sizeM; i++){
    if(Search(result, dataM[i].data, maxlen, dataM[i].size) == 1){
        for(int j = 0; j < maxlen; j++){
            result[j] = dataM[i].data[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, пояснить, что значит в данном случае "данные не инициировались", никак не могу понять.

Comment: расширил ответ, функция лексиграфического выбора требует доработки, добавлю чуть позже

Comment: @sne11js поправил функцию лексикографического выбора